# The Adaptive card FAQ sentence is split into an unreadable format in MS Team Channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards

The following screenshot FAQ response is split into an unreadable format like "Personal" is showing as "Per" in the first line and then remaining words are showing in the next line. Is there any solution to this issue?

[image]

**Template Title Content**

*Title 1: "Found an answer for you in **Global BA Systems & Processes** ➡️ **Personal Data**"*

*Title 2: "You need to raise a ticket in support@abcdefghi under category [Personal Data Change Request](https://abcdefghi.abcdefg-abc.com/supportxaabcdefghi?id=sc_ball_item&sys_id=ds123ffedbf68300da04fe9b0c13467b), providing new home address."*

**C# Code**

```
 public static Attachment DisplayFAQResponse(string buttonTitleForImage,string FaqMessage, 
        string FaqAnswer, string RequestId = null, ListImageUrl= null )
   {
   var faqResponseCard = new AdaptiveCard("1.2");

    var msteamsProp = new MsTeamsObject()
    {
        Width = "Full",
        Wrap = true,
    };
    SerializableDictionary<string, object> msteams = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>();

    msteams.Add("msteams", msteamsProp);

    faqResponseCard.AdditionalProperties = msteams;

    faqResponseCard.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
    {
        AdditionalProperties = msteams,
        Text = FaqMessage,
        Separator = true,
        Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.ExtraLarge,
        Wrap = true
    });

    faqResponseCard.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
    {
        AdditionalProperties = msteams,
        Text = FaqAnswer,
        Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.Default,
        Wrap = true,
        Separator = true
    });
    
    

    return new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
        Content = faqResponseCard
    };
}`
```

**Platform**

- Web ( MsTeams Web http://teams.microsoft.com ) Microsoft Teams
- Version 1.4.00.32771 (64-bit). It was last updated on 12/15/2021.

**Adaptive Card Version**

- 1.2

Comment: you should add the template used for the card

Comment: @Gusman I have used the above code to bind the value coming from FAQ and there is no separate template for this integration. All the adaptive card template creation happening inside the 'DisplayFAQResponse' method that I have already mentioned in this thread. I have updated the exact title content for the card that I have used in the adaptive card template. Here UI is MS Team Channel and 'DisplayFAQResponse' is returned as an attachment that we are directly posting into the channel using the send activity method.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth - Tried the same code my end and its showing correctly  - [here screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJggb.png). Maybe try updating Teams client.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT what version of Team client you are using? how to update the team client version?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/5003 - Updated on this duplicate thread.

Comment: Sure, Here I have posted a similar question (customer reported) because of the 6 days delayed response from the Github community - [Thread](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/6881).